# cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<ChaseState>' to 'std::shared_ptr<State<Cow>>

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

When trying to call a method `setCurrentState` Im getting the error:

> StateMachine<Cow>::setCurrentState(std::shared_ptr<State<Cow>>)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<ChaseState>' to
>   'std::shared_ptr<State<Cow>>'

This indicates that a `std::shared_ptr<ChaseState>` is not a `std::shared_ptr<State<Cow>>` but why is it not?

The call to the function:

```
std::shared_ptr<ChaseState> initialState = std::make_shared<ChaseState>();
m_stateMachine->setCurrentState(initialState);
```

**State.h**

```
#pragma once
template <class entity_type>
class State
{
public:
    virtual void enter(entity_type*) = 0;
    virtual void execute(entity_type*) = 0;
    virtual void exit(entity_type*) = 0;
};
```

**ChaseState.h**

```
class Cow;
class ChaseState : State<Cow>
{
public:
    ChaseState();

    // Inherited via State
    virtual void enter(Cow*) override;
    virtual void execute(Cow*) override;
    virtual void exit(Cow*) override;
};
```

In my StateMachine I have private variable:

```
std::shared_ptr<State<entity_type>> m_currentState;
```

and the setCurrentState function:

```
void setCurrentState(std::shared_ptr<State<entity_type>> s) { m_currentState = s; }
```

As I understand the derived class ChaseState is a State (behause it inherits from state).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your inheritance `public`. Class inheritance is private by default, meaning that you cannot cast from `Derived` to `Base` because the inheritance is not recognized outside of the class itself (same as how private members cannot be accessed outside the class).

To fix, make your inheritance public:

```
class ChaseState : public State<Cow>
//                 ^^^^^^
```